# Types being included as controls in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I am working in Storybook building some components and patterns in TypeScript. I seem to have "types" showing in the controls on one of my stories :-( The types that are showing are from my `MediaCardProps` type that extends `Post`. I am doing something wrong I just don't know what!

1. This is my component

[image]

2. These are the types

[image]

3. This is the story

[image]

4. This is the unexpected result. Anyone know why Storybook is displaying types as controls? TIA

[image]

Comment: Consider using `import type ...` or `import { type ... }`. These imports will be erased in the JavaScript so Storybook cannot use them.

Comment: This is expected right? All the props are converted to controls. Or do as @caTS suggested :P

Comment: In the MediaCard component I am already deconstructing the props so I thought that only these would show as controls. It shouldn't matter if I allow a thousand types to be associated to this component I don't expect these to show as controls. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have found a way to do it. Rather than extending all from Post I am now using `Pick` so it looks a bit like this: 
`export type PostProps = Pick<Post,"excerpt" | "featuredImage" | "date" |"slug"| "title"
>;`

Comment: I thought you had to explicitly pass props into the component to show in controls. Didn't expect it to ready the types too